# How to Disable Default CSS in ASP.NET Web?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every time I run my web page, it shows the ASP.NET default page rather than my map view created through TGOS API. It works well on VS Code, but not on VS Community that always set default CSS style to override my page. How to disable the default CSS style in ASP.NET Web project?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Getting Start TGOS MAP</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.tgos.tw/TGOS_API/tgos?ver=2&AppID=x+JLVSx85Lk=&APIKey=in8W74q0ogpcfW/STwicK8D5QwCdddJf05/7nb+OtDh8R99YN3T0LurV4xato3TpL/fOfylvJ9Wv/khZEsXEWxsBmg+GEj4AuokiNXCh14Rei21U5GtJpIkO++Mq3AguFK/ISDEWn4hMzqgrkxNe1Q==" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        function InitWnd() {
            var pOMap = document.getElementById("TGMap");
            var pMap = new TGOS.TGOnlineMap(pOMap, TGOS.TGCoordSys.EPSG3826);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0px" onload="InitWnd();">
    <div id="TGMap" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the framework you are using for Asp.Net Web forms or MVC? Regardless, According to my understanding you need to change the default page in Asp.Net. And the way to do that depends on weather you are using Web Forms or MVC

Comment: I'm using neither Web Form nor MVC. I only add html file to my C# .NET Framwork project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net MVC your new view automatically adds the layout page to itself. To force it to not use the _Layout.cshtml you can add the following Razor code at the top of your view:

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using MVC. My project is based on ASP.NET Web Application.